# How to read from a file into a JTextArea (GUI) line by line?

Tags: java, string, user-interface, jtextarea, filereader

I am reading in from a file (which is a list of names and their contact numbers) and displaying it in a textarea in a GUI. The file reads in fine and the text is displayed. But I want each line from the file to be on a new line on the GUI. So each name and address to be on a new line. How do I do this?
This is my code so far, but it doesn't display each line from the file on a new line on the GUI.

```
public void books() throws IOException {
        String result = " ";
        String line;
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(newFile("books2.txt")));
        while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;`
        }


        area1 = new JTextArea(" label 1 ");
        area1.setText(result);
        area1.setBounds(50, 50, 900, 300);
        area1.setForeground(Color.black);
        panelMain.add(area1);

    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to read it line by line if you're going to display whole file anyway?

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Because I want a new line for each name, and at the moment it displays in just one line on the GUI and does not fit on.

Comment: but do you realize that it displays in just one line *precisely because* you are reading it line by line?

Comment: @SergeyTachenov How do I change it so that it will display each new line from the file on a new line in the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to read it line by line. Something like this will do:

```
String result = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("books2.txt")),
                           StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This, of course, will require more memory: first to read bytes, and then to create a string. But if memory is a concern, then reading the whole file at once is probably a bad idea anyway, not to mention displaying it in a `JTextArea`!

It may not handle different line endings properly. When you use `readLine()`, it strips the line of all endings, be it CR LF, LF or CR. The way above will read the string as-is. So maybe reading it line-by-line is not a bad idea after all. But I've just checked—`JTextArea` seems to handle CR LF all right. It may cause other problems, though.

With line-by-line approach, I'd do something like

```
String result = String.join("\n",
        Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("books2.txt"),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

This still strips the *last* line of EOL. If that's important (e. g., you want to be able to put text cursor on the line after the last one), just do one more `+ "\n"`.

All of the above requires Java 7/8.

If you're using Java 6 or something, then the way you do it is probably OK, except that:

1. Replace `LineNumberReader` with `BufferedReader`—you don't need line numbers, do you?
2. Replace `String result` with `StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder()`, and `+=` with `result.append(line).append('\n')`.
3. In the end, use `result.toString()` to get the string.